# How to create grid layout in Blogger with title, image and button inside every grid

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogs

I am working on creating an affiliate website in blogger.com. i need a layout which resembles this.

for your ease, https://www.technikkss.com/ this is the website i am referring to.

[image: Grid Layout Blog]

How can i recreate easily?, i have no knowledge of html or css. if there is any such theme/layout is available for free. please let me know.

PS: I searched with keyworks like affiliate marketing template, grid template for blogger yet the results i found are not satisfying my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should share some code, however if i understood you correctly this is a basic idea of what you need using `bootstrap 5`

*Update*
I just realized that this was not displaying properly in the snippet preview. So i have made it responsive!
View in full page to get an idea of what it would look like!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap shop</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.0.2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <h2 class="text-center mb-5">My Blogger Shop</h2>
    <div class="container mx-auto mt-2">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="card mx-2 mt-2 col" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="https://placebear.com/640/360" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Mens Watch <br> March 20, 2022</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2 mt-2 col" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="https://placebear.com/640/360" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Mens Watch <br> March 20, 2022</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2 mt-2 col" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="https://placebear.com/640/360" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Mens Watch <br> March 20, 2022</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2 mt-2 col" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="https://placebear.com/640/360" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Mens Watch <br> March 20, 2022</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3 text-center">
            <div class="card mx-2 mt-2 col" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="https://placebear.com/640/360" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Mens Watch <br> March 20, 2022</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2 mt-2 col" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="https://placebear.com/640/360" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Mens Watch <br> March 20, 2022</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2 mt-2 col" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="https://placebear.com/640/360" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Mens Watch <br> March 20, 2022</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mx-2 mt-2 col" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="https://placebear.com/640/360" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Mens Watch <br> March 20, 2022</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `col` class will shrink the columns as per the view-port. Its better to use flex grid. Example `col-md-3`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am well aware of this. Just put the above for examples sake.

Answer (score 0):

I would use for it flexbox system. Like that:

```css
.w {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
}

h4 {
  color: lightgray;
}

.card button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300px">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <h4>Sub title</h4>
    <button class="buy">Buy</button>    
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300px">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <h4>Sub title</h4>
    <button class="buy">Buy</button>    
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300px">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <h4>Sub title</h4>
    <button class="buy">Buy</button>    
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300px">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <h4>Sub title</h4>
    <button class="buy">Buy</button>    
  </div>
  
    
</div>
```